# Is there any way to set a read-only (const) variable in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, constants

Is there any way to set a read-only (const) variable in cmd?
I was wondering if there's any way to make a read-only variable in cmd, but I don't found any results.

I have that code:

```
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
    echo.Required parameter missing.
    exit /B 2
)
if "%~1"=="--SETVAR:var" if "%~2"=="%__CONSTVARIABLE__%" goto main

if defined "%~1" if "%___%~1_type___%"=="__CONSTVAR__" (
    echo Could not set '%1' as constant variable as it's already a constant variable
    exit /B 1
)
set "__CONSTVARIABLE__=%~1"
set "___%~1_type___=__CONSTVAR__"
start /b cmd.exe /c %0 --SETVAR:var %__CONSTVARIABLE__% "%~2"
exit /B 0
:main
cmd /c set "%__CONSTVARIABLE__%=%~3" ^& exit /B
set "%__CONSTVARIABLE__%=%~3"
goto main
```

My idea was to make a resident batch file in current console. But I'm facing two problems:

1. This doesn't set the variable as it runs on another cmd instance
2. If this works, it uses ~10% of the CPU because it's on a constant loop and if we define too many variables the computer starts going **really** slow.

So, is there any way to do that in a better way?

Comment: Like you will do: `const var=10`. A variable that you can't write to it another value once it is set.

Comment: ok, so then it is a __constant__ and not a __variable__. Variables are exactly that, it can vary. Anyway, no, any variable you set on `cmd` can be changed, unless you just don't change them or use a hardcoded value. But please elaborate where you want to set and retain this constant so I can make out what you want to achieve please.

Comment: I want to save that constant into memory. There are read-only variables in cmd like _`%firmware_type%`_

Comment: If your aim is to create a System environment variable, read the output of `Setx /?`

Comment: @Anic17 but that is completely differen :). Will see if I can post an answer for you, but might take some time as it is alot of info.

Comment: @T3RR0R not the same thing ;)

Comment: I am aware. As you have already stated @Gerhard any variable in batch can have it's value modified, however at least with a System environmental variable, the original value will persist when a new cmd session is started.